# bash-fu: i want a script to be able to run a cleanup program upon ^C

Tags: macos, bash

my dev workflow is something like this:

```
term-1 $ ctl-C #kills tail
term-1 $ catalina7 stop
term-2 $ ant
term-1 $ catalina jpda start && tail -f logs/catalina.out
```

how can i hook the ^C on tail, to run `catalina stop`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this in a bash script and use the built-in `trap` command like this:

```
trap "catalina stop" INT
ant
catalina jdpa start && tail -f logs/catalina.out
```

The first argument to `trap` is a command that is to be run when the given signal (the second parameter) is received. To trap Ctrl-C you use the `INT` signal. Another useful signal is `EXIT` which calls the trap every time the script ends.

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing, except using parens to create a subshell without needing to write a script file: `term-1 $ (trap "catalina stop" SIGINT && catalina jpda start && tail -f logs/catalina.out)`